# Who owns the Finch House?

Tags: what-remains-of-edith-finch

Played through the game last night, and one detail we stumbled on is: given the number of years between

> when Edith leaves the house and returns, and then to her child returning

.. does the Finch line actually own the house anymore?

While Dawn gives Edith a key, it's notably *not* the key to the front door or the gate blocking access. And it's implied strongly that Dawn never returned, so you'd think she'd just sell the place off rather than keep an empty (and in her mind cursed) building on the books indefinitely. (Or perhaps just empty the place out, since Edie Sr. isn't there anymore to stop her.)

Answer (score 1):

You have to remember that Edie Finch most likely had ownership of the house. She was the first in their family to immigrate from Norway to America, and lived through all the lives and deaths of her entire family, all the way down to Dawn and Edith.

Remember that Dawn lived her life watching her family die off one by one. It's far more likely she chose not to ever bother or think about the family's "curse" that caused so much misery for her life after leaving with Edith.

Comment: The problem I see there is that the house still exists, so who has been paying the land taxes and the utilities after the night Dawn and Edith leave?